# style.transition.width 0px makes image just disappear

Tags: javascript

I created this little function as part of an image scroller all its meant to do is reduce the size of the image to a 0px width before the next pic is loaded in and grows the grow part works fine but this wont.(I have tried several variations of this as well)

```
function shrinkimage()
{
    var image = document.getElementById('test');    

        image.style.display = "block";
        image.style.styleFloat = "left";
        image.style.width = "1024px";
        image.style.transition = "width 0.5s ease 0s";
        image.style.width = "0px";
    }
```

the image just disappears when I want it to shrink to the left hand side
any help would be much appreciated.
if it helps the next thing to happen is the image src gets changed

```
function rotate(imageNumber) {
           var myimage = new Array;
        //Modify these variables as needed
        //vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        myimage.push("data/images/borderlands.jpg");
        myimage.push("data/images/creed.jpg"); 
        myimage.push("data/images/darksouls.jpg");
        myimage.push("data/images/fable.jpg");
        myimage.push("data/images/fallout.jpg");
        myimage.push("data/images/gears.jpg");
        myimage.push("data/images/halo.jpg");


        var time = 5000; //5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds            
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        var image = document.getElementById('rotator');

        if (imageNumber < myimage.length) {

            shrinkimage();
            hideimage();


            setTimeout(function () {image.src = myimage[imageNumber];}, 500);



            growimage(); 

            imageNumber++;
        }
        else {
            imageNumber = 0;

            shrinkimage();
            hideimage();

            image.src = myimage[imageNumber];

            growimage();

            imageNumber++;
        }
        var t = setTimeout("rotate(" + imageNumber + ")", time);
    }



function shrinkimage()
{
var image =document.getElementById('rotator');
    image.style.styleFloat = "left";
    image.style.width = "1024px";
    image.style.transition = "width 0.5s ease 0s";
    image.style.width = "0px";
```

}

```
function hideimage()
{
var image =document.getElementById('rotator');
{
    image.style.display = "none";
}

function growimage()
{
 var image =document.getElementById('rotator');
        image.style.display = "block";
        image.style.width = "0px";
        image.style.styleFloat = "right";
        image.style.transition = "width 0.5s ease 0s";
        image.style.width = "1024px";
```

}

```
.slider {
    border: 0px;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 400px;
    transition:  width 0.5s ease 0s;
    -mox-transition:  width 0.5s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition:  width 0.5s ease 0s;
    -o-transition:  width 0.5s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition:  width 0.5s ease 0s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider_box{
    width:1024px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 5px #000000 solid;
}
```

if you cant see what I'm trying to do the image rotator shrink the old image to the left and grows the new one to the left. the grow part works beautifully but the shrink wont

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the image with the transition in css

```
#test {
    transition: width 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

then in the function just change the `style.width`

```
function shrinkimage() {
    var image = document.getElementById('test');
    image.style.width = '0px';
}
```

Comment: Nope that just makes the image disappear (well not disappear but instantly shrink to width:0px; even when I extend the time any other ideas?

Comment: Check out this jsbin to see my example working - http://jsbin.com/ikIlIGA/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

If the source changes before the transition completes, you're going to have that problem, much the same way that transitions won't work if you set the css to `display: none`. Try making sure that the image source changes after the transition is complete. For instance, you could use the following:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    image.src = 'path/to/newSource.png';
  }, 500);
```

Comment: Could you set up a jsFiddle with example images?

Comment: please explain jsFiddle/ and if I can I will

Comment: set timeout makes the fist image grow again then change

Comment: Please just put up a fiddle so I can see this happening and provide you some better advice.

Comment: although it doesn't work the same on there as it does on the browsers I have installed (IE, FF, Chrome)